# Can OGC Simple Feature polygon's interior boundaries share an edge?

Tags: polygon, ogc, standards, compliance

Is the polygon pictured below compliant with the OGC Simple Feature standard?

There are two interior boundaries that share a segment so intuitively I would say it is not but I have not been able to find any confirmation in the [documentation](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa) (in the 1.2.1 version, polygon is described on pages 26-28).

There are "rules that define a valid polygon" and I don't see there anything that would exclude polygons whose interior boundaries touch, but I also don't understand why, based on those rules, are some of the example polygons in Figure 12 invalid so I must be missing something.

[image: Polygon]

Comment: 6.1.11.1(c) rejects this configuration ("nearby points cannot be common")

Comment: Ok, so according to this, they could share a vertex because then the nearby points would not be common? So, how come in the figure 12, the first example shows a polygon where boundaries only touch (but cannot be represented as a polygon)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that rings which share a segment are denied by the rule 6.1.11 c)

> No two Rings in the boundary cross and the Rings in the boundary of a
>   Polygon may intersect at a Point but only as a tangent.

Inner rings which touch at one point (intersect as a tangent) is OK.

```
POLYGON (( 0 0, 0 5, 6 5, 6 0, 0 0 ), ( 2 2, 3 2, 3 4, 2 4, 2 2 ), ( 3 2, 3 1, 4 1, 4 2, 3 2 ))
```

[image]

Case when inner rings intersect along a line and thus have an infinite number of common points is not OK.

```
POLYGON (( 0 0, 0 5, 6 5, 6 0, 0 0 ), ( 2 2, 3 2, 3 4, 2 4, 2 2 ), ( 3 3, 3 1, 4 1, 4 3, 3 3))
```

[image]

The right way to express the above is to combine the inner rings

```
POLYGON (( 0 0, 0 5, 6 5, 6 0, 0 0 ), ( 2 2, 3 2, 3 1, 4 1, 4 3, 3 3, 3 4, 2 4, 2 2 ))
```

[image]

Test with PostGIS and rings touching at one point:

```
select ST_IsValidReason(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 0 0, 0 5, 6 5, 6 0, 0 0 ), ( 2 2, 3 2, 3 4, 2 4, 2 2 ), ( 3 2, 3 1, 4 1, 4 2, 3 2 ))'));
    Result: Valid geometry
```

Test with PostGIS and rings intersecting along a line:

```
select ST_IsValidReason(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON (( 0 0, 0 5, 6 5, 6 0, 0 0 ), ( 2 2, 3 2, 3 4, 2 4, 2 2 ), ( 3 3, 3 1, 4 1, 4 3, 3 3))'));
Result:
"Self-intersection[3 2]"
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! But I have the same question as above - how come in the figure 12, the [first example](https://imgur.com/Pq8IJfL) (of features that are not compliant} is a polygon where boundaries only touch? I know in this case they are exterior and interior boundaries that touch, but still - why this is not possible?

Comment: That case breaks the rule `The interior of every Polygon is a connected point set`. The hole in the example cuts the polygon into two pieces. The geometry must be expressed as a multipolygon with two members.